# Как добавить SDK QuickBlox в Android проект?

Tags: java, android, sdk

Вот файл build.gradle (Project: MyApplication)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url="file:///d:/quickblox-android-sdk-master"
        }
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Вот файл build.gradle (Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.q.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:3.2.0'
}
```

Вот что выдает Gradle Build:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
>   Could not find com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:3.2.0.
>        Required by:
>            MyApplication:app:unspecified

Что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 1):

добавьте в корневой build.gradle файл это

```
maven {
   url "https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
}
```

А в build.gradle файл модуля добавьте это

```
compile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:2.5.1@aar"    
compile("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:2.5.1@aar") {
     transitive=true
}
```

Comment: pavel163, спасибо за отклик, но хотелось бы добавить, что мне нужно добавить именно локальный репозиторий (url "https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/" мне не подходит, у меня плохой интернет), a compile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:3.2.0@aar"    
compile("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:3.2.0@aar") {
     transitive=true
} это то же самое что и compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:3.2.0' (начиная с версии 2.6.1)

Comment: тогда скачайте эти модули, которые вам нужны и попробуйте подключить как модулю

Comment: я скачал sdk и скопировал на диск D. url указал вроде бы правильный, но выдается ошибка: Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'. Could not find com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:3.2.0. Required by: MyApplication:app:unspecified Что посоветуете?